# grep look around match not working

Tags: regex, grep

I'm told that grep has lookaround support.  I'm trying to exclude the line with grep in the answer because obviously that's usually going to be there.  I just want to check that my mysqld server is up basically.

The Regex expression I'm trying:

```
^(?!.*grep)(?=.*mysql).*
```

The Command line.  The top line I'm trying to match, the bottom line I'm trying to exclude.

```
root:~# ps aux | grep mysqld_safe
root     28012  0.0  0.1   4408   712 pts/0    S    18:00   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
root     29167  0.0  0.1   9392   900 pts/1    S+   20:51   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld_safe
```

Here's my query:

http://regex101.com/r/qK3cI5

```
# ps aux | grep '^(?!.*grep)(?=.*mysql).*'
(nothing)
```

Comment: To _look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes_ why don't you try [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep), from [procps](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) package?

Answer (score 6):

- to use look ahead/behind you need add `-P` option to your grep (if your grep supports it). since PCRE supports them.
- there is a common trick when you grep the `ps` output, but want to exclude the `grep` process itself, you can for example:

  ```
  ps -ef|grep [m]ysql
  ```

or

```
ps aux|grep [m]ysql
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would go with

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mysql
```

Which just excludes lines containing *grep* before "greping" for *mysql*

Comment: ...and if performance is an issue, know that this is **a lot** faster than the single-grep, lookaround version.

Comment: instead, you can simply run: `ps aux | grep "[m]ysql"`

Answer (score 1):

You may try `awk`,

```
ps aux | grep mysqld_safe | awk '$12~"--color=auto" {next;} {print;}'
```

OR

```
ps aux | grep -oP '^(?!.*grep)(?=.*mysql).*'
```